# How to solve issue related to ActionName in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am working on Asp.Net MVC application where I don't want to display define action name in url. So I am applying ActionName with Action in controllers. But when I am defining ActionName with Action then it's not working and showing error page of 404 - not found. So please can you guide me to resolve this issue ?

```
public ActionResult Login()
{
   //code
}
```

when I am passing url like domain/Login then it's working properly.

```
[ActionName("SignIn")]
public ActionResult Login()
{
   //Code
}
```

but when I am applying ActionName like above then it's showing error page of 404.

I check about this issue on google but not any work for me.

Comment: Do you actually navigate to `/SignIn` when applying the attribute?

Comment: I am redirecting to Login action from another controller.

Comment: How about just use `[HttpGet("SignIn")]` instead of `[ActioName]`?

Comment: Please show how you are redirecting.

Comment: I am redirecting from Index action to there by using `return RedirectToAction("Login");`

Comment: You should use `RedirectToAction("SignIn")`.

Comment: I am thinking that ActionName is using for change naming conversion of action. So I have use RedirectToAction link at many places so it will be little bit of awkward to change naming in whole project application. So is there any way to RedirectToAction with Login name and in Url it should be display SignIn name ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33716438/asp-net-removing-the-action-name-from-the-url Please check above solutions.

Comment: @zeny ASP.NET MVC works in terms of actions. The action name is what is important. The method name is not important at all. There is a convention that by default the method name is taken as the action name, which may look like the method name is the action name, but it is not, and you face the distinction as soon as you override the default convention with an `ActionName`. If you don't like that, then it will probably be easier for you to remove the `ActionName` attribute and rename the method to be `ActionResult SignIn()`. Then the VS will properly rename it in all places.

Comment: @GSerg when I make Action name and method name same then it's working properly but when I write different Action name rather then method name then it's causing issue.

Answer (score 1):

While returning from the controller , for the same controller you have to specify like

```
return View("Login");
```

If you are redirecting to another controller action

```
return RedirectToAction("ActionName", "ControllerName");
```

and if you are using javascript to navigate for this action,use like

```
   window.location.href="/ControllerName/SignIn";
```

Try

```
[ActionName("SignIn")]
 public ActionResult Login()
 {
    //Code
   return View("Login");
 }
```

Comment: Please mention your comments while downvoting.